# NameError: name 'generate_dendrogram' is not defined

Tags: python, networkx

So I am trying different functions in the community library:http://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html and when I get to community.generate_dendrogram, an error prompted as NameError: name 'generate_dendrogram' is not defined.

```
import networkx as nx
import community 
G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100, 0.01)
dendrogram = generate_dendrogram(G)
```

I have imported all the required packages but the error still exists.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: In your code you have `dendrogram = generate_dendrogram(G)` instead `dendrogram = community.generate_dendrogram(G)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `generate_dendrogram` is not loaded into the current scope.

To fix this, you have two options:

1. Import/load `generate_dendrogram`
2. You already have the `community` module loaded. You can be explicit and call the `generate_dendrogram` inside that module.

Option 1:

```
import networkx as nx
from community import generate_dendrogram
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100, 0.01)
dendrogram = generate_dendrogram(G)
```

Option 2:

```
import networkx as nx
import community
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100, 0.01)
dendrogram = community.generate_dendrogram(G)
```